# Can't find definition of model

Tags: ltspice

Im trying to do simulation of this circuit but I took this mistake.

After I clicked "Ok(TAMAM)"
then new txt opened:

> Error on line 550 : sine(0 15 1k 0 0 0)    Unable to find definition of
>   model "0" Fatal Error: Vo and in are paralleled making an over-defined
>   circuit matrix. You will need to correct the circuit or add some
>   series resistance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely that you haven't set the voltage source correctly.

I assume, that you have added the line `SINE(0 15 1k 0 0 0)` as a spice directive instead of changing the voltage source. (At least that way I get a similar error).

So instead of adding this line as a text (or spice directive), right click on the voltage source, select advanced, then select the radio button labeled sine and type in the required numbers.

It should look like this:
[image: Voltage source settings]

After this, you have to delete the existing `SINE(0 15 1k 0 0 0)` line, otherwise it will still upset the simulator.

Now what often happens is that the text will overlap with some part of your schematic making it ugly to look at. You can use the drag or move tool and click on the offending text to move it around:

[image: The move tools]

And make it look like this:

[image: Schematic after moving]

If this answer did not solve the second error as well, please leave a comment and I'll try to figure that out as well.

Comment: Firstly thanks for helping and spend your time 
But This is homework circuit so ı cant change it looks/designs. 
And your first solution didnt solve :/  ( which is select none to sine and giving params)

Comment: @PeterMacLeish have you deleted the `SINE...` line after changing the voltage source? Otherwise the line will still upset the simulator. I haven't mentioned this in my answer...

Comment: I deleted both of them and did again . but Everything is same :(

Comment: @PeterMacLeish this is a bit hard to believe (being EXACTLY the same) - maybe to make it easier to help you, can you edit your question and add the Spice Netlist of the circuit? To do so, go to View -> Spice Netlist. When you paste it into your question, select all of it and press the "code" button, it'll then get a nicer format.

Comment: are you here? I need to ask you another little questino

Comment: @PeterMacLeish I am here from time to time, if you have another question, just post it on this site. There are many people out there willing to answer provided your question is according to the rules.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an additional error:

> Error: Vo and in are paralleled making an over-defined circuit matrix. You will need to correct the circuit or add some series resistance.

In LTspice, by default, there is a series resistance of 1m\$\Omega\$ (specified through the internal `Rser`). But the moment you add a coupling directive (`K L1 L2 ...`), the inductors' series resistance becomes null. This, along with the voltage source, which, by default, also has zero resistance, causes the matrix solver to calculate an infinite current at startup, since you apply a sine with zero offset, resulting in a \$-\cos {\omega t}\$ current.

The solutions are simple: either add `Rser=<value>` to the voltage source, or add `Rser=<value>` to the inductor in parallel with the voltage source.

In rest, looking at your picture, there's nothing wrong with the circuit, it should work (it's safe to leave those traling zeroes). The inductances seem a bit small, but that's up to you to know what you are trying to do (maybe just testing).

But, this error is strange, so, if you don't mind, could you click on `View > SPICE Netlist`, select all, then `Ctrl+C` (it doesn't work with `RClick > Copy`) and paste here?